# Azure Web App wwwroot duplicates on publish

Tags: angular, azure, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

Steps:

1. create empty Web App on azure
2. create empty .NET Core Web API
   project in VS2017
3. This project will include a wwwroot folder. After configuring my angular 5 app to build into wwwwroot/dist I publish from VS to the azure web app
4. After publishing the site does not load on azure. In the web app settings the application root is set to `site\wwwroot`
   [image: Azure WebApp Application Settings]
5. After ftping(publishing) into the web server I can see the current file structure to the app is `/site/wwwroot/wwwroot` So off the bat that is weird. wwwroot is already nested within itself.
6. To get the website to load I simply update the Application Setting to point to `/site/wwwroot/wwwroot`.

Great. It works. However if I need to go back and publish a new change to the site the folder structure on the webserver changes in response to the updated application settings! Now the site will not load and the new file system is `site\wwwroot\wwwroot\wwwroot` I can update the Application Settings on azure again and set that path as the root and again the site will work. But now I have two copies of the website on the server and I cant help but thing this is not a 'best practice'. Not to mention if I publish the site again the file system will just append another `wwwroot` and break the site.

What is going on here? How can I publish my site with a proper file system structure. When the site looks like this I have to manage multiple  `web.config`s and Its making it difficult for me to figure out how to get the angular router working. This is all done with initial microsoft presets (the web app and the webapi app).

I feel like ideally the entire website should be under wwwroot with one web.config

Is this the case? Thank you for reading. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't the Web API project have to be configured to return static files from wwwroot? I don't think it knows to serve them otherwise.

Comment: How do you publish your website to Azure? Do you using Visual Studio 2017 built-in Publish feature with **Publish Profile** from Azure App Service?

Comment: @WillHuang Yes. I right click the project and select publish. Then I pick the webapp on my azure account and proceed from there.

Comment: Creating a brand new Azure Web App and a brand new WebAPI project with an index.html inside of wwwroot and publishing does not even work. The API route will work but index.html will not render. Is this a microsoft issue? I feel like it isnt since no one seems to have this issue.

Comment: Do you using ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to serve your `wwwroot` as a static files, you should change a little bit in your `Startup.cs` file.

Try to add the following code snippet into your `Configure()` method in the `Startup.cs` file.

```
        app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions() {
            DefaultFileNames = new List<string>() { "index.html" }
        });
        app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Here is the full sample code:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions() {
            DefaultFileNames = new List<string>() { "index.html" }
        });
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Right now, you should deploy your web app into Azure without problem.

Comment: This solves the issue. wwwroot is no longer duplicated every publish and I no longer have to specify a second virtual application directory for my api. Thank you very much

Comment: the web.config rule for rewriting to SPA routes has now broken. But that is a new hurdle.